# Collapse and Expand Tree structure in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a help on collapse and Expand using Javascript.
Here is my running code (.html)

> ```
>  <h2>Test</h2>
>   <html lang="en">
>   <head>
>      <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
>      <title></title>
>      <script type="text/javascript">  
>         function toggleDisplay(element) 
>         {       
>           element.style.display = element.style.display === 'none' ? '' : 'none'; 
>         };
>         function toggleDisplayAll(elements) 
>         { 
>           for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++)
>            {
>               toggleDisplay(elements[i]);
>            }
>         }   
>      </script>
>    </head>
>    <body>  
>     <ul>
>       <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')); return false;" href="#">Name:</a>
>         <ul style="display:none;">
>         <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')); return false;" href="#">Address: </a>
>             <ul style="display:none;">
>             <a onclick="toggleDisplayAll(this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('li')); return false;" href="#">Subject: </a>
>                 <ul style="display:none;">
>                     <li style="display:none;">Id
>                     </li>
>                 </ul>
>             </ul>
>          </ul>
>      </ul>
>   </body>
>  </html>
> ```

If you run this html, you will get out put as

> ```
>  Name
> ```

on click of Name, it is showing all the child elements

> ```
>  Name:
>     Address:
>         Subject:
> ```
>
> On click of Subject it is showing Id
>
> ```
>   Name:
>     Address:
>         Subject:
>                . Id
> ```
>
> What i want here is each child should open only on parent click.

When run the html, only Name will dispaly

> ```
>   Name:
> ```
>
> On click of Name, only Address will be displayed as a child element.
>
> ```
>    Name:
>         Address:
> ```

Onclick of Address, only Subject will display

> ```
>    Name:
>         Address:
>             Subject:
> ```

Than finally on click of Subject, id will show up

> ```
>    Name:
>         Address:
>             Subject:
>                  . Id
> ```

How to implement this tree structure. what i am doing wrong here. please suggest me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check this:

```js
$('.expand').click(function() {
  $('ul', $(this).parent()).eq(0).toggle();
});
```

```css
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="expand">Root</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="expand">Child</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="expand">Super Child</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to use jQuery, you can try this:

```js
var expander = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');

for (var i = 0; i < expander.length; ++i) {
  expander[i].onclick = function() {
    var ul = this.parentElement.querySelectorAll('ul')[0];
    
    if (ul.offsetHeight > 0) {
      ul.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      ul.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="expand">Root</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a class="expand">Child</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a class="expand">Super Child</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on this question, do you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Is there any way i can do it using Javascript.

Comment: Thank you Nanang and Oka.

Thanks for showing the different way's of implementation.

both the solutions are working as i wanted. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

You want to target just the first child element, instead of looping through all of them. You should also try to separate your logic from your markup. Give [unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) a read.

```js
function toggle() {
  var ls = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
      styles, display;

  if (ls) {
    styles = window.getComputedStyle(ls);
    display = styles.getPropertyValue('display');

    ls.style.display = (display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none');
  }
}


var eles = document.querySelectorAll('.ele');

Array.prototype.slice.call(eles).forEach(function (e) {
  e.addEventListener('click', toggle);
});
```

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.ele {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ele:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="ele">One</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span class="ele">Two</span>
        <ul>
          <li><span class="ele">Three</span>
            <ul>
              <li><span class="ele">Four</span></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure JavaScript

```js
document.querySelector('.tree-structure').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const el = e.target;
  const sibling = el.nextSibling.nextSibling;

  if (el && el.className == 'toggle' && sibling) {
    sibling.classList.toggle('show');
  }
});
```

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tree-structure">
  <li>
    <button class="toggle">1st Level</button>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <button class="toggle">2nd Level</button>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <button class="toggle">3rd Level</button>

            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="toggle">3rd Level</button>

            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="toggle">2nd Level</button>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <button class="toggle">3rd Level</button>

            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="toggle">3rd Level</button>

            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="toggle">1st Level</button>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <button class="toggle">2nd Level</button>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <button class="toggle">3rd Level</button>

            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="toggle">3rd Level</button>

            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button class="toggle">2nd Level</button>

        <ul>
          <li>
            <button class="toggle">3rd Level</button>

            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <button class="toggle">3rd Level</button>

            <ul>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button class="toggle">4th Level</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```