# HTML collapse/expand tree not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to collapse category tree with multi hierarchy. I tried so many answers from stack, but it's not working. Can anyone please help me?

I tried this code : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30945775/7727479

**Actual Result :**

- First display Test 1 and Test 3
- Then, click on Test 1 => On click Test 2 and Test 8 should be display
- Then, click on Test 2 => On click Test 4 and Test 7 should be display
- and so on.

**UPDATE :**

[image]

**Snippet :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getChild = $('ul.categories').children('li');
  getChild.each(function(i, v) {
    if ($(v).data('parentcategory') == "0") {
      $(v).addClass('active-collapse');
    }
  });
  $('div.categories-list li').click(function() {
    var main_category = $(this).data('parentcategory');
    $('ul.sub', $(this).parent()).eq(0).toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
div.categories-list {
  width: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}

ul.categories,
ul.sub {
  border-top: 1px solid #c3cfd9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.categories li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.categories li a {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #FCFCFC;
  color: #3f729b;
  border: 1px solid #c3cfd9;
  border-top: 0px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

ul.categories li a:hover {
  text-indent: 5px;
}

ul.sub {
  display: none;
}

.activeUi {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories-list">
  <ul class="categories">
    <li class="child active-collapse" data-parentcategory="0" data-id="1">
      <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:1%">Test 1</a>
      <ul class="sub" data-parentcategory="0" data-id="1">
        <li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="1" data-id="2">
          <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 2</a>
          <ul class="sub" data-parentcategory="1" data-id="2">
            <li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="2" data-id="4"><a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:10%">Test 4</a></li>
            <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="4" data-id="5"><a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:20%">Test 5</a></li>
            <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="4" data-id="6"><a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:20%">Test 6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="2" data-id="7"><a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:10%">Test 7</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="sub" data-parentcategory="0" data-id="1">
        <li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="1" data-id="8"><a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 8</a></li>
        <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="8" data-id="9"><a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:40%">Test 9</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="single active-collapse" data-parentcategory="0" data-id="3"><a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:1%">Test 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem was in you html structure, if you want to create a level, you need to create `li` in that level with `anchor` in the `li` element.

For example to add **TEST 2.2** in **TEST 1.0** you need to find next ul.sub after the `anchor` that is for **TEST 1.0** and add another `li` with `anchor` , and if you want to create another submenu in **TEST2.2** you need to create `ul` with class sub and and another `li`

```
<li class="single deactive-collapse">
    <a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 2.2 LAST</a>
    <ul class="sub" >
        <li class="child deactive-collapse">
            <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:10%">Test 3.2 LAST</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And here is the snippet

```js
var addById = function (parent, id, name) {
    $('div.categories-list li').each(function (i, e) {
        if (parent === $(e).data("id")) {
            if (!$(e).find("ul.sub").length) {
                $(e).append('<ul class="sub"></ul>');
            }
            element = '<li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="' + parent + '" data-id="' + id + '"><a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:5%">' + name + '</a></li>';
            $(e).find("ul.sub").append($(element));
            return true;
        }
    });
};
addById(1, 123, 'dynamically');
addById(15, 124, 'dynamically');

$(document).ready(function () {              
    $('div.categories-list li > a').click(function () {
        var main_category = $(this).data('parentcategory');
        $('ul.sub', $(this).parent()).eq(0).toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
div.categories-list {
    width: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
}

ul.categories,
ul.sub {
    border-top: 1px solid #c3cfd9;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.categories li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.categories li a {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #FCFCFC;
    color: #3f729b;
    border: 1px solid #c3cfd9;
    border-top: 0px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 150ms ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

ul.categories li a:hover {
    text-indent: 5px;
}

ul.sub {
    display: none;
}

.activeUi {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="categories-list">
    <ul class="categories">
        <li class="child active-collapse" data-parentcategory="0" data-id="1">
            <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:1%">Test 1.0</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="1" data-id="2">
                    <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 2.0</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="2" data-id="4">
                            <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:10%">Test 3.0 LAST</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="2" data-id="5">
                            <a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:10%">Test 3.0 LAST</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="2" data-id="6">
                            <a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:10%">Test 3.0 LAST</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="1" data-id="7">
                    <a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 2.1 LAST</a>
                </li>
                <li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="1" data-id="8">
                    <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 8</a>
                    <ul class="sub" data-parentcategory="8" data-id="9">
                        <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="8" data-id="9">
                            <a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:40%">Test 9</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="1" data-id="10">
                    <a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 2.2 LAST</a>
                    <ul class="sub">
                        <li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="10" data-id="11">
                            <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:10%">Test 3.2 LAST</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <!-- PUT EXAMPLE CODE HERE -->
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="child active-collapse" data-parentcategory="0" data-id="12">
            <a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:1%">Test 1.1</a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li class="child deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="12" data-id="13"><a class="li-child-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 2.1 LAST</a></li>
                <li class="single deactive-collapse" data-parentcategory="12" data-id="14"><a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:5%">Test 2.1 LAST</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="single active-collapse" data-parentcategory="0" data-id="15"><a class="li-single-text" style="padding-left:1%">Test 1.2 LAST</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Did you checked that in my code, Test 8 and Test 9 available. But, It's not display ? Can you please solve that?

Comment: I've added them to the snippet, now I see what you did there i will fix the snippet with data-parentcategory and data-id, so you can get it right

Comment: It's working perfect. Can you please just one help me to add node level in li dynamically? I will aceept and upvote your answer.

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: I have added one function in snippet addById it will search in all li for data-id, so if you want to addnew sub element into Test 9 for example just try addById(**9**,'YOUR ID HERE', 'SOME TEXT'); 
You can edit it as you wish

Comment: But why don't you use some plugin like this [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/demo/)

Comment: Yes you are right. But, I need to do custom logic. So, I don't use third party.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199399/discussion-between-ankita-patel-and-angel-bonev).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have some issues with the structure of ul li. Please have a look at my demo. You can add your classes and attributes to your will. It won't hamper.

```js
document.querySelector('.categories').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const el = e.target;
  const sibling = el.nextSibling.nextSibling;

  if (el && el.className == 'toggle' && sibling) {
    sibling.classList.toggle('show');
  }
});
```

```css
div.categories-list {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}

ul.categories,
ul.sub {
  border-top: 1px solid #c3cfd9;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.categories li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.categories li a {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: #FCFCFC;
  color: #3f729b;
  border: 1px solid #c3cfd9;
  border-top: 0px !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

ul.categories li a:hover {
  text-indent: 5px;
}

ul.sub {
  display: none;
}

.activeUi {
  display: block;
}
ul ul {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories-list">
    <ul class="categories">
        <li >
            <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 4</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 5</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 6</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 7</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 8</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 9</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="toggle">Test 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul for your effort. +1 for that :) But, I solved by myself. But, I have small issue. I added screenshot in question. I want to add node level in li tag like that.

Comment: If you don't understand what I want. Then, you can please check in above answer's chat room.